# Replacing part of raster with another one using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, arcgis-10.5, replace

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.5 and I am unable to find how to replace a part of a raster with another raster.

I have a Raster for topography and for a part of it I need to recreate a past morphology which was done by creating a new raster from isoline but only for a part of it as briefly shown here:

[image: replace a part of a raster with a smaller raster]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you already masked your "green" raster with NoData values where you don't want to replace the "red" values, Then you can use conditions in raster calculator (Map algebra tool). This would be a code like below

```
Con(IsNull("green"), "red", "green")
```

Which means: if the green raster is noData, then use the value of the red raster, otherwise use "green".

In the environment variable, make sure that you set the extent to maximum extent of inputs.

Comment: thanks. But infortunately the small green raster is smaller than the red one. So is it possible to create a mask larger than the greenraster or should i mask the red one and then use the mask to compute.

Comment: this shouldn't be a problem: absence of data = NoData. Just make sure that your output has the size of the largest raster